# How to add to an Object in an Array using Mongoose when using ".create"

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, express, mongoose

So I want to make a phonebook app where one contact has multiple numbers with certain categories. 
I can't seem to grab those values from the form and input it into my Contact object. 
Here is my model :

```
var contactSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    name: String,
    surname: String,
    address: String,
    email: String,
    number: [
        { phone: String,
        number: Number,
        default: Boolean }
    ]
});
```

This is my form:

```
<p>Add Number <span id="plus"> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></span></p>
                <div class="row add">
                    <div class="col-3">
                        <select class="form-control mr-sm-2" name="phoneType">
                            <option value="Mobile">Mobile</option>
                            <option value="Telephone">Telephone</option>
                            <option value="Fax">Fax</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-5">
                        <div class="form-group"><input class="form-control" type="number" name="phoneNumber" placeholder="Number..."></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-4">
                        <select class="form-control mr-sm-2" name="phoneDefault">
                            <option selected value="false">Set as default</option>
                            <option value="true">Yes</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

And my Create route:

```
app.post("/", function(req, res) {
    var phoneType = req.body.phoneType;
    var phoneNumber = req.body.phoneNumber;
    var phoneDefault = req.body.phoneDefault;
    var number = {"phone":phoneType, "number": phoneNumber, "default": phoneDefault};
    Contact.create(req.body.contact, {$push: {"number":[number]}}, function(err, createdContact){
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect("/new");
        } else {
            console.log(createdContact);
            res.redirect("/");
        }
    });
});
```

When I create a Contact using this i just get an empty array as number:[];
Nothing gets inserted. 
What I want to be able to do is to add multiple objects to the number array.
In my form I can press the plus sign and a new input will be shown to write new info.
Example of number array:

```
    number:[
{phone:"fax"
numebr:"1234"
default: true},
{phone:"mobile"
numebr:"133234"
default: true},
{phone:"telephone"
numebr:"123234"
default: true},
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your can do like this

```
app.post("/", function(req, res) {
    var phoneType = req.body.phoneType;
    var phoneNumber = req.body.phoneNumber;
    var phoneDefault = req.body.phoneDefault;
    var number = {"phone":phoneType, "number": phoneNumber, "default": phoneDefault};
    var contact = new Contact({
           anyField : req.body.contact,
           number : number
     });
     contact.save(function(err, createdContact){
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect("/new");
        } else {
            console.log(createdContact);
            res.redirect("/");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The form is bigger than shown here. It contains inputs like name, surname, addres etc.. which i named name=contact[name] etc..

Comment: means you also want to insert `req.body.contact` in data base ?

Comment: It stores the numbers in the db but not as separate objects, though i think i have to have dynamic forms with different names?